# Vue.js filter id on array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I filter like this on vue.js?

```
$followid = [1,2,3,4,4,5];
foreach ($array as $element)
   if (in_array($element->id, $followid))
   endif
endforeach
```

Comment: You need to improve your question, I fail to see `?` (question mark).

Comment: Which array exactly?

Comment: It looks like you just want to check whether `display.id` is in `this.editlistAssesments`, which I assume is an array based on `indexOf`. You could just replace: `<div v-if="display.id | ifInArray">` with `<div v-if="editlistAssesments.includes(display.id)">`.

Comment: sorry variable editlistAssesments change to followid , follow id have values followid= [1,2,3,4,4,5],

Comment: display.id check in_array on followid =[1,2,3,4,4,5]

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a filter for this usecase. I am not sure that you have access to 'this' in a filter. I encourage you to use a computed property that returns the array to display.

```
computed: {
    actifOnline: function() {
        let self = this;
        return this.online.filter((o) => {
            return self.editlistAssesments.indexOf(o) > -1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to `let self = this` if you are using an arrow function :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return bool in filter:

```
ifInArray: function (value) {
    return this.editlistAssesments.indexOf(value) > -1 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: i have try like this,    <span  >@{{ display.id | ifInArray }}</span>

Comment: and error [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Comment: and i try <div v-if="display.id | ifInArray">

Comment: error [Vue warn]: Property or method "ifInArray" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up on this question trying to solve a similar problem, I think.

I used a *method* as my solution, I had an array of users and I needed to match the current logged in user with the managers array of users on my model:

```
methods: {
    isManager( task, current_user ) {
        return task.managers.find(x => x.id === current_user.id);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<button v-if="isManager(task, current_user)">Approve</div>
```